# Mankind starting from fallen spaceship crew

Tags: story-identification, books

There is a book about a spaceship crashing on Earth, the survivors couldn't repair the ship, so had to live on Earth. After a while, only a few survived. Slowly, the survivors forgot how to use any tools left with them. The writer suggested that the mankind started from these survivors. I can't remember the title or the author. Can anyone remember reading such a book?

Comment: Do you remember anything else, like when you read it?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AncientAstronauts

Comment: That is honestly a pretty common theme, can you remember if it was actually a full book or a story in an anthology, also when you say "the writer suggested" was the book actually meant to be fiction?

Comment: Hello chdsl, and welcome to [scifi.se]. Thank you for your question. As @Valorum has pointed out, astronauts becoming the first humans is an often used idea. Is there anything about the book that makes it recognisable? What did the cover look like? When did you read it? Where? You can [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/154352/edit) your question to include any details you might remember, how insignificant they may appear. Meanwhile, have you taken the [tour] yet?

Comment: I think I read it about 10 years ago. I know it might be a common theme. I'm trying to find the exact book. If anyone knows any title, please let me know. I might still find that book. I think this book had been written a long time ago, maybe sometime in the beginning of the last century. I think one spaceship crashed while landing, and there were some still out in the space. This one lost connection with that fleet.

Comment: According to the [ever-popular TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarthAllAlong), this plot was so heavily used in the sixties that it became a Discredited Trope, and has now reached the point where if two astronauts are stranded on a primitive planet the audience will *assume* it is Earth.

I would suggest having a look at the shows listed in the link and see if any of them ring a bell.

Comment: Does either of these ring a bell? The humans are on a planet where all the Flora and Fauna are gigantic to them. Giant ant's (human sized) Giant Fungus (Deathcap) etc. Second, Seed-ship genetically modifies the embryo's to various environments on a planet, story centers on Humans in water finally figuring out that the surface tension is not an impenetrable barrier and build a transport vehicle to go beyond the barrier (carry's water).  As others point out the numbers of those kind of stories is huge, the two I gave you hopefully spurs some other "unique" memories.

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help. Nothing rings a bell yet.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds a bit like [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe).

Here the Golgafrinchan Ark Fleet Ship B crash-lands on "an utterly insignificant little blue green planet orbiting a small unregarded yellow sun in in the uncharted backwaters of the unfashionable end of the western spiral arm of the Galaxy" - wich suggests (and is later confirmed) to be the prehistoric Earth.

Comment: *"Sounds a bit like The Restaurant at the End of the Universe."* And 42 (hundred) other sci-fi stories..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like "[Genesis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6477402-genesis)" By H. Beam Piper.

A ship crashes on Earth and survivors use weapons and tools to survive but as they wear out or run out of ammo they must learn to make do and over time, forgetting technology and becoming our distance ancestors.

The story is available on the [Project Gutenberg website](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/18105).

Comment: Thank you anyway Valorum, but I prefer it my way!                               Sounds like "GENESIS" By H. Beam Piper. Ship crashes on Earth and survivors use weapons and tools to survive but as they wear out or run out of ammo they must learn to make do and over time forget technology and become out distance ancestors. The story is available on the Project Gutenberg website.

Comment: My thought was the 'Giants' series by (i think!!) James P Hogan

Comment: Piper was my first thought too.